# How to fix "npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy "

Tags: npm

I am trying to install `npm install --global bower` and it throws me an error:

```
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/bower failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 13.25.26.4:8080
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm timing npm Completed in 147880ms

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\aksha\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-06-27T05_03_12_739Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have run these commands and it solved for me

npm config delete proxy 
npm config delete http-proxy 
npm config delete https-proxy